# WCF Authentication Service with SSL encryption

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ssl

I have created a WCF authentication service and all works well. When I am trying to implement SSL encryption to the communication, I get the following error:

*There was no channel actively listening at https://myDomain/WebSite/MyAuthenticationSvcWrap.svc. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.*

The web.config of the http service host:

```
<system.serviceModel>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AppServiceBehaviors" name="WebSite.System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" bindingNamespace="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200" contract="WebSite.System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" >
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>   

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AppServiceBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and client app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService">
                <security mode="None">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>                        
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://mydomain/WebSite/MyAuthenticationSvcWrap.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService"
            contract="AuthenticationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The https service host:

```
<system.serviceModel>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AppServiceBehaviors" name="WebSite.System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" bindingNamespace="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200" contract="WebSite.System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" >
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>   

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AppServiceBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and app.config of client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService">
                <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>                        
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://mydomain/WebSite/MyAuthenticationSvcWrap.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService"
            contract="AuthenticationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Actually I have changed the mode attribute of the  element to Transport in the basicHttpBinding of both files and also changed the client endpoint address from http to https. I must also note here that by hitting https://mydomain/WebSite/MyAuthenticationSvcWrap.svc in a browser finds the page and gets a response.

Can anybody suggest why this behaviour might be happening?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve the issue, although the answer doesn't make things any better for me, clarity-wise.

The solution was to tick "Require SSL" at SSL Settings in IIS. It doesn't make any sense because the way I perceive it, if Require SSL is not ticked, means that an SSL request can still be handled the same way.

Furthermore, the error messages continued, although this time were easier to resolve. It proved out that if the Security mode was set to 'Transport', I had to omit the Assembly name from the name attribute of the  element. In other words, it had to be exactly the same with the service name declared in the .svc file. In my case System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService, while WebSite.System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService was giving an error. The contract attribute had to be changed accordingly.

What surprises me though is not why this happened but why this did not happen when the mode attribute was set to 'Nothing'. Although my application now works the way I want, I would still like to gain insight to the previous issues for the shake of gaining a better understanding. If anyone can help any further, I would be grateful.

Thanks alot.